# load data from mysql with jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a drop down list (ddlAccount) which i can choose an item from it and do a db query in test.php to retrieve corresponding data, then output an input element with the returned data.

This is my javascript code:

```
function load1(){
$('#divAccountNum').load('test.php?accountInfo=' + document.getElementById('ddlAccount').value , '' ,function() {
alert('Load was performed.')}); 
}
```

load1 function called when i change the dropdown list items, and it takes the value of the selected option and sends it to test.php in a parameter called "accountInfo".

my html:

```
  <select name="ddlAccount" id="ddlAccount" onchange="load1();">
    <option value="1"> Account1</option>
    <option value="2"> Account2</option>
    <option value="3"> Account3</option>
  </select>

  <div id="divAccountNum" >
  </div>
```

And test.php :

```
if($_GET['accountInfo'])
{
    $account = $accountDAO->load($_GET['accountInfo']); //mysql query
        //print an input holding account number as its value
    echo "<input type='text' name='txtAccountNum' id='txtAccountNum' value='".$account->accountnumber."'/>"; 
}
```

The problem is that nothing happened when i choose an option (nothing appear in div (divAccountNum))
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** 
I used @thecodeparadox 's bit of code and it works and i found a solution for the problem that i mentioned in the comments below which is that when choosing one item from the dropdown list it shows the value in input element and loads the form again. The solution is in:
[jQuery Ajax returns the whole page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586217/jquery-ajax-returns-the-whole-page)
 So my jquery code now looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#ddlAccount').on('change', function() {  
$.get('testJquery.php?accountInfo=' + $(this).val(), function(accountNum) {
    //console.log(accountNum);
    $('input#txtAccountNum').val(accountNum);
   });
});
```

And testJquery.php :

```
if($_GET['accountInfo'])
{
    $account = $accountDAO->load($_GET['accountInfo']);
    $accountNum = $account->accountnumber;
    echo $accountNum;
}
```

And at last i added input element in divAccountNum which has id="txtAccountNum"

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. You'll need to tell us what the code is doing, what errors you're seeing, as well as what the expected behavior is and what the actual behavior is. Telling us there is simply a problem does not give us a lot to go on. You can use the **edit** link under the question to add more details. Good luck!

Comment: If you use jQuery why don't you use selector in `document.getElementById('ddlAccount').value` like `$('#ddlAccount').val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you don't give enough info about your problem, but you can try this:

```
function load1(){
  $('#ddlAccount').on('change', function() {  
    $.get('test.php?accountInfo=' + $(this).val(), function(response) {
       $('div#divAccountNum').html(response);
    }, 'html');
  });
}
```

**NOTE:**

1. `$('#ddlAccount').on('change',` fires when dropdown change
2. `$.get('test.php?accountInfo=' + $(this).val()..` send a get(ajax) request to `test.php` with value selected from drop down
3. parameter `response` with in `$.get()` second parameter callback function is the response from the server
4. `'html'` as third parameter of `$.get()` for data type you return, as you return a html so it is `html`.

for more info read:

**[change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)**

**[$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)**

Comment: I tried this but nothing happened, input element still doesn't appear in the page.

Comment: I'm using Smarty. Could this be a problem?!

Comment: don't think so that Smarty cause problems. Does you php script work well? debug the response with `console.log(response)` just before `$('div#divAccountNum').html(response)`

Comment: There are no errors in php. I also echo-ed an alert with the returned account number in php and it appeared.

Comment: replace the line in your php `echo "<input type='text' name='txtAccountNum' id='txtAccountNum' value='".$account->accountnumber."'/>";` with `echo '<input type="text" name="txtAccountNum" id="txtAccountNum" value="'. $account->accountnumber .''"/>';` and also remove `html` from `$.get()`

Comment: Ok this works but i removed 'function load1(){}' and leave the rest in '$(document).ready()'. But there is another problem which is it loads the whole form again after the input element. Thanks for your help and patience.

Answer (score 0):

To get selected option value from select input use:

```
$('#ddlAccount option:selected').val()
```