# Not getting the success callback for an ajax query to my php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

*Edit: changed $.alert() to alert()*

I've got a file, planner.php that uses JQuery to send an ajax request to the same page.
Using the debugger, I can see that the php correctly gets the request, accesses my database, and then sends the data. However even after sending it I get no success callback in the javascript. What's wrong?

JQuery:

```
$(function()
{
    $.post('planner.php', {"want": "keys"}, success_func, 'json');
});

function success_func(result)
{
    //This is never called :(
    alert("Worked");
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
require_once "./php/couch.php";
require_once "./php/couchClient.php";
require_once "./php/couchDocument.php";

if (count($_POST) > 0 && array_key_exists("want", $_POST)) {
    $couch_dsn = "http://localhost:5984/";
    $couch_db = "subjects";
    $client = new couchClient($couch_dsn, $couch_db);
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $response = $client->getView('subject_views', 'keys');
    echo json_encode($response);  //This all seems to work fine
}
?>
```

It's that simple. All of the PHP code there is just accessing couchDB which you don't have to worry about because I know that $response is set correctly.

Comment: Anything in the console? Is the result wellformed, add an error function to see

Answer (score 2):

For knowing where the ajax call is done or faced a error

```
 $(function()
 {
 $.post('planner.php', {"want": "keys"},function(){
  alert( "success" );
 })
 .done(function(){
    alert("second success");
  })
 .error(function(){
    alert("error");
  });
});
```

link : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0):

This is probably be cause there is no such thing like `$.alert()`, use simple `alert()` instead.

Also your `success_func` is declared below the ajax call, move it up before `$.post();`

EDIT:

as the function is declared, there is no need to type it before executing.

Comment: Function declarations are hoisted. There is no need to move it.

Comment: Okay I changed it to alert(), but I know that wasn't the problem because it wasn't causing any errors as it was. And success_func still isn't being called.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like that it may be your sucess function not calling

```
var data = 'want=keys';
$.post(
  'planner.php',
  data
).success(function(resp){
   json = $.parseJSON(resp);
   alert(json);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Credit to vivek for giving me a method to work out the problem.

Basically I fundamentally didn't understand how php worked. The code for sending the POST response was halfway down the page, so PHP was sending back the *entire page* along with any extra json I had encoded, and then JQuery attempted to parse this html page as json, failed, and then didn't run the success function because it never succeeded in its request. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2586250/2148718) for some more insight

The obvious solutions are:

1. Make a new page for the response
2. Put the php at the top of the
   page.

I ended up going with option #2 for simplicity's sake.

Thanks everyone!