# jQuery AJAX get MySQL data returns entirety of index.html

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

**Related Thread: [jQuery Ajax returns the whole page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586217/jquery-ajax-returns-the-whole-page)**

The above thread is related, and this seems to be a somewhat common problem, but the answer in that thread doesn't exactly help in my situation.

When an image on my page is clicked, a jQuery function is called, and in that function is an Ajax declaration:

```
//click an image
$(".img_div").click(function() {

    //get integer stored in alt attribute and pass to variable
    var altCheck = $(this).find('.modal_img').attr('alt');

    //get MySQL data
    $.ajax({

        //php file to grab data
        url: "get.php",
        type: "post",
        datatype: "json",

        //pass above variable to php file
        data:{ ajaxid: altCheck },

        success: function(response){
            //log data to console
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("test");
        }
    });
```

I'm trying to log the received data into the console purely as a test right now, but I'm getting the entire index.html page logged into the console instead.

A connection has been made to the database and stored in variable `$db` prior to any image clicks.

Here is my **get.php** file:

```
<?php

//variable from jQuery
$value = filter_var($_REQUEST["ajaxid"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($value);

//variable passed to SQL statement
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT FROM table WHERE screeningId = ?");
$sql->bind_param("s",$value);

//Get data
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    //output data
    echo $row['url'];
}
?>
```

Comment: First identification, you mentioned datatype as "json", but your ajax response is not json.

Comment: I tried changing this to "text", but the result was the same.

Comment: try to direct run get.php in browser with query string. Ex, `http://...../../get.php?ajaxid=sample_value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First identification, you mentioned datatype as "json", but your ajax response is not json. So Try like this,

```
<?php

//  Make DB connection variable($conn) available here
//variable from jQuery
$value = filter_var($_REQUEST["ajaxid"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $value);

//variable passed to SQL statement
/*$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT FROM table WHERE screeningId = ?");
$sql->bind_param("s",$value);*/
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE screeningId = '$value'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

//Get data
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$temp = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    //output data
    array_push($temp,$row['url']);
}
echo json_encode($temp);
?>
```

For debug purpose, try to direct run get.php in browser with query string. Ex, http://...../../get.php?ajaxid=sample_value.

Comment: Thank you. Running the page isolated gave a syntax error! Good tip. Fixing and then checking your code..

Comment: Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Comment: Also you are missing mysql connection in get.php file. First make `$conn`(DB connection) variable available in get.php and pass it into `mysqli_real_escape_string()` funtion. Ex, 
 $conn->real_escape_string($value); OR mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $value);

Comment: Yes, I established connection within the file and that seemed to fix it.

Comment: Cheers!!  :)   (Y)