# jQuery Ajax - $sql is an object Error

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

**UPDATE at bottom of question**

I'm getting the error:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object
>   given

Questions about this are incredibly common on Stack Overflow - my apologies in advance. I haven't been able to find a good answer for my specific problem. If there is a thread that addresses this, please let me know.

Here is my Ajax code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "get.php",
        type: "post",
        datatype: "json",
        data:{ ajaxid: altCheck }, //this is an integer passed to MySQL statement
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("test");
        }
    });
```

**get.php**

```
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect("...", "...", "...", "...");

$value = filter_var($_REQUEST["ajaxid"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $value);
var_dump($value); //checking to see what $value is at this point

$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE screeningId = ?");
$sql->bind_param("s",$value);


//THIS LINE THROWS THE ERROR
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$temp = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    //output data
    array_push($temp,$row['imageURL']);
    }
echo json_encode($temp);
?>
```

The fourth line of code `var_dump($value);` outputs `string(0)`.

---

**UPDATE: MySQLi**

```
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect("...", "...", "...", "...");

$value = filter_var($_REQUEST["ajaxid"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $value);

$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE screeningId = ?');
$query->bind_param('s', $_GET[$value]);
$query->execute();

if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $query)) {
    while ($url = mysqli_fetch_object($result, 'imageURL')) {
        echo $url->info()."\n";
    }
}

?>
```

---

Screenshot of MySQL table data columns:

[image]

Comment: I don't do PHP, but the error (warning) message you quote is pretty specific. Your call to `mysqli_query()` is not passing a string in the second parameter. Your `$sql` variable is not a string. So...

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure why it's not a string. `$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE screeningId = ?");` - it's initially declared here, but for some reason it's not registering as a string.

Comment: Well again I don't do PHP, but I would expect a `prepare()` function in any language to return an object. You are using it as an object yourself when you call the `$sql->bind_param()` method on the next line.

Comment: It looks like your are mixing `mysqli` and `PDO` syntax...

Comment: I see. A lot of this code is from the answer from my previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44251933/jquery-ajax-get-mysql-data-returns-entirety-of-index-html

Comment: You want to use [`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)

Comment: So what do you want to use `mysqli` or `PDO` ? [HERE](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059) is a comparison article between the two.

Comment: I'm more familiar with `mysqli`. The answers I've gotten in terms of making the ajax calls more secure I believe were in `PDO`? I assumed they could be used together.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Thanks, I'm reading this comparison now.

Comment: Elsewhere on my site, I'm using `mysqli`.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette do you recommend I do this in `PDO`?

Comment: You can use both in one site... But not both in the same request to DB ;) It is easier to choose one and get used to it.

Comment: It is your choice. My personnal preference always been PDO... Just because that's the first I learned.

Comment: And, just to be clear, the statements with `->` , that is `PDO`, right? Sorry, I'm very new to this.

Comment: No.. `->` is an object operator... That is PHP. look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2588183/2159528)

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks.

Comment: Don't escape with parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Okay... 8 edits spent on mysqli... Enought!
Here is how **I DO** using PDO. And it WILL work first shot.
I have a separate file for the database connection info.

**dbconnection.php:**

*(The advantage of the separate definition file is one place to update the user password when needed.)*

```
<?php
// Database connection infos (PDO).
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=[DATABASE_NAME];host=127.0.0.1';
$user = '[DATABASE_USER]';
$password = '[USER_PASSWORD]';


try {
  $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Connexion failed : ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Now in your PHP files where a database request has to be done, include the PDO definition file, the just request what you want:

```
<?php
include('dbconnection.php');

// JUST TO DEBUG!!!
$_REQUEST['ajaxid'] = "1";

// Database request.
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE screeningId = ?");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_REQUEST['ajaxid']);
$stmt->execute();

if (!$stmt) {
   echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
   print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
   die;
}

// Looping through the results.
$result_array =[];
while($row=$stmt->fetch()){
  array_push($result_array,$row['imageURL']);
}

// The result array json encoded.
echo json_encode($result_array);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried this, but still getting `Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given`

Comment: Trying this again.

Comment: Hold on... That will not create a json yet... I will edit again.

Comment: I see, okay. Yes, that wasn't throwing any errors, but was outputting entirety of index.html - I'm not sure why that keeps happening.

Comment: Okay, giving it a go.

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function encode() `

Comment: lolll My bad... `json.encode($arrayTojson)` sould be `json_encode($arrayTojson)`... Arrgg... so many similar syntax...

Comment: Not me, you all are being patient with ME. I don't know what I'm doing and appreciate the help and extra knowledge!

Comment: So... Is it working with `json_encode($arrayTojson)` ?

Comment: That didn't seem to work, it said there was an error with encode(). Let me check one more time.

Comment: Actually, my apologies, that seems to work, but it outputs an empty `[ ]`. I've added a picture of the data columns for this table at bottom of my question, just in case maybe I'm doing something stupid or typing something wrong?

Comment: Okay... Last try... I changed the `while` loop a bit.

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array()`

Comment: At least... The script is executing until that line... Almost there. I re-edited again.

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given`

Comment: It's the same result

Comment: Let's give a try with what I got working for years... ;) PDO !!

Comment: Okay, giving this a try, one moment

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR)`

Comment: Thrown on line `var $result_array =[];`

Comment: Right!... lolll `var` is some JavaScript deformation in my brain. remove `var` in front of `$result_array`. I edited.

Comment: Okay that fixed it. I'm back to an empty `[ ]`

Comment: I get the empty `[ ]` when I run the page isolated, and when I run it with the actual website (ie a variable gets passed to get.php) the entire index.html gets outputted

Comment: Yes, I changed that, too. Why would it output my index.html file, though? I don't get that.

Comment: mmm... Is the code I provided the only code in get.php?

Comment: `success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
   },` - is that right? For the output into the browser console? That's in the page where the initial ajax call is

Comment: Try `success: function(response){ console.log(JSON.stringify(response)); },`

Comment: Hmm no that still seems to output the whole index file, as in: `"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html ng-app=\"app\"> ......`

Comment: That IS strange.

Comment: It's not getting the URLs from the database, and it's also outputting index.html. I must have something really wrong somewhere..

Comment: I added a "JUST TO DEBUG" line... Now accesse get.php directly... Like `http://your-domain/get.php`

Comment: the `url` in the jquery ajax call was the wrong path. I'm an idiot. I'm accepting your answer, thanks for the help. I actually learned a lot.

Comment: I'm definitely using your code for this, so thank you.

Comment: What you don't know is always harder then what you know. ;) Don't feel cheap, it is the same for everyone. ;)

Comment: mysqli certainly is not that hard... I just don't know it. ;)

Comment: You have an awesome portfolio. Thanks for taking the time. I'm bookmarking your profile and will definitely recommended people to you when I can.

Comment: Thanks! ;) That would be great. I love killin.. ahem... fixing bugs. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using mysqli_* all other place in your project, update your get.php as below.

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("...", "...", "...", "...");

$value = filter_var($_REQUEST["ajaxid"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $value);
//var_dump($value); //checking to see what $value is at this point

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE screeningId = '$value'";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$temp = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    //output data
    array_push($temp,$row['imageURL']);
    }
echo json_encode($temp);
```

**EDIT**

With respect to bind param with mysqli,

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('db_server', 'db_user', 'db_passwd', 'db_name');


$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE screeningId = ?';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$value = filter_var($_REQUEST["ajaxid"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $value);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
$temp = array();
while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  array_push($temp,$row['imageURL']);
}
echo json_encode($temp);
```

Comment: The OP should keep the parameterized query.

Comment: This got rid of all errors, thank you. Now I'm just getting an empty array output: `[ ]`.

Comment: @chris85 does that mean maybe I should do this whole thing in PDO?

Comment: echo $sql; and try run the printed query direct in the database and check it out.

Comment: No. It means you should keep this line: `$sql->bind_param("s",$value);` and keep the `?` in the $sql string instead of $value.

Comment: Replacing `$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE screeningId = '$value'";`  with `$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE screeningId = ?");
$sql->bind_param("s",$value);` throws two errors

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given` and `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given`

Comment: Look at the "Security" example in the comparison article I gave you. ==> "mysqli, prepared statements"

Comment: @coffeebot `PDO` and `mysqli` both support parameterized queries, you need to use the manual for whichever driver you are using. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette looking at that example right now. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my code above to be (I believe) all `mysqli` but still getting `Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given`

Comment: @coffeebot: use the edited code. It should work. If not please let me know.

Comment: It works in that there aren't any errors, but the output is `[ ]`, and trying this from the actual page outputs all of index.html

Comment: prinrt your query and try run direct in mysql server to check whether it has records or not.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, that seemed to produce results as it should. Weird.

Comment: then print_r($row); before array_push and amke sure the column names...

Comment: `print_r($row['imageURL']);`
 `array_push($temp,$row['imageURL']);` tried to add that before array_push, but it didn't print anything? I don't understand what's going on

Comment: `print_r($row);` not `print_r($row['imageURL']);` may be you don't have imageURL column in your table?

Comment: I've added a picture of all data columns from the MySQL table at bottom of question. Tried `print_r($row)`, and that doesn't seem to print anything either.

Comment: `screeningId` is of type integer. Does that make a difference at all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145415/discussion-between-naga-and-coffeebot).

Answer (score 0):

Select Data With PDO in `get.php`:

```
<?php 

    if( isset($_POST['ajaxid']) ) {
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE screeningId = :screeningId"); 
      $stmt->execute(array(':screeningId' => $_POST['ajaxid']));
      $row = $stmt->fetch();
    }
?>
```

You configure PDO to throw exceptions upon error. You would then get a `PDOException` if any of the queries fail - No need to check explicitly. To turn on exceptions, call this just after you've created the `$conn` object:

```
$stmt->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```